# C# DataGridView, prevent from deleting invisible rows in the selections

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm developing Winform C# project. Which has 2 components:

- DatagridView to show data
- TextBox to filter these Data Rows by string. Once it's including filter keyword, the Data Row would be Visible and the other not relevant would be Invisible.

Now, I'm implementing a delete row function which calling an event from `dataGridView.UserDeletingRow` to delete row by row. I found out the bug that when I used combination of filter function from TextBox and `shift key + click`, it's not work as expected result. Let's say:

My datagridView including:

- AA
- AAB
- BC
- A

TextBox filter string `A` => datagridView will visible 3 rows:

- AA
- AAB
- A

I would like to delete these 3 visible rows, then my actions are:

- `shift key + click` 3 rows `from top to bottom`, press `Delete key` => it worked, `UserDeletingRow` event was called 4 times, and then `3` rows were removed, the `BC` row visible = false.
- `shift key + click` 3 rows `from bottom to top`, press `Delete key` => it failed, `UserDeletingRow` event was called 4 times, and then `4` rows were removed (included the invisible `BC` row). I have debugged this `BC` row turn visible. whereas it should be visible.
- `ctrl key + click` and `drag-select` both work correctly.

```
 MyDataGridView.UserDeletingRow += (s, e) =>
 {
     if(e.Row.Visible)
     {
          //delete
     }
 };
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it is not visible (`!e.Row.Visible`) then you can delete it or what exactly is your problem?

Comment: when deleting row by row, it suddenly turned BC row from invisible to visible. I don't know why.

Comment: When deleting from a list you have to start at the end and move toward the beginning.  It you have a list 1,2,3,4,5 and you remove 3 then every item above three move down one index.  So removing is done like this : for(int i = myList.Count() -1; i >= 0; i--){ you code here}

Comment: @jdweng as i said, the UserDeletingRow event of datagridView auto called to delete row by row when I deleted rows, and it worked correctly if I used shift + click to select from top to bottom, but when I used shift + click to select from bottom to top, the selection also included visible rows and invisible rows, but when UserDeletingRow was called it auto turned all selection rows to visible. I don't know why, maybe this is a bug of the datagridView ?

Comment: Sometimes the DGV get properties set that you cannot fix.  Simplest solution is to delete the DGV from the designer and add a new one which will set all values back to default.  You could also look at the designer.cs file to see what values are being set, but it may not show the ones that are creating the issue.

Comment: I have to disagree with your conclusion that this is possibly a bug in the `DataGridView`. More importantly, for something like this you should provide a “complete” example that will reproduce the problem. Currently your question shows no valid code, therefore we can only assume that what you say is true. And unfortunately, in my tests, what you say is happening is NOT happening when I do the same steps.

Comment: Without a solid reproducible example, I can only assume something else is going on. Can you provide an example that will demonstrate what you describe? Without it, I have to assume something else (that you are not providing) is going on since my tests do not reflect what you say is happening.

Comment: There are a ton of questions, like, how is the grid populated? If it has a data source, what “type” is it? How are you “filtering” the data and reflecting that “filtered” data back to the grid as there are numerous ways to do this? How exactly are you “deleting” the data from the grid? I tried filtering in numerous ways and all worked as expected, so I question “how” you are actually “deleting” the “selected” rows from the grid. I am just saying that in most cases, selecting the rows from the row headers and pressing the delete key removed the proper rows without having to wire up any events.

Comment: Which bring me to my last question… which is the awkward looking code that you did supply. The code appears to be the grids `UserDeletingRow` event which we will assume works (as it would not compile for me), however assuming it DID work…

Comment: The `if` statement makes no sense. This event fires when the user presses the “delete” key and has one or more “rows” selected by clicking on the row header(s). Given this, IF the user was able to “SELECT” the row… then HOW could it possibly be “Invisible”? The fact that the user “selected” the row in the first place is proof enough that the row is NOT invisible. ???

Comment: I can only guess you may be filtering the data by making certain “GRID” rows “invisible” which if you are, then this is the wrong approach.